# Scripts/stylesheets not found in Cordova iOS app

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I am attempting to port an Angular 1 web app to iOS using Cordova. I've created the Cordova project, added the platforms I need (browser, ios), and copied my production Angular app into the `/www` folder.

When I run `cordova run browser` the app loads as expected in Chrome.

When I run `cordova run ios` the simulator appears, I see the default splash screen, but then all I get is an empty white screen. Using the Safari inspector/console I found that my script and stylesheet references were failing to load:

`Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server.
file:///cordova.js
file:///app.js
file:///app.css
etc...`

This is my first Cordova project and I'm not sure how to debug this. Any insight or debugging tips are appreciated.

---

**Screenshots:**

Ignore the suffixes on the filenames...those are dynamically generated and I took screenshots from multiple builds. They all match when I run the app locally.

**Folder structure**

[image]

**Script tags in index.html**

[image]

**Console errors (from Safari console while app is running on iOS simulator)**

[image]

**config.xml (default values...just to get the damn thing working)**

[image]

Comment: create screen shots of folder structure then easily i can help you . Otherwise i write down a simple example for you  .Thanks

Comment: @HassanALi updated with screenshots.

Comment: had you added ios platform ?

Comment: @HassanALi yes I did

Comment: Please also update your config.xml here .Thanks

Comment: @HassanALi updated

Comment: after successful addition of platform this tag <engine name="ios" spec="~4.2.1" />  will added to your config.xml Hopefully you can understand your mistake

Comment: @HassanALi I just added the engine tag and re-ran everything. Still not working :( Thank you for all of your suggestions so far though :)

Comment: cordova platform add ios --save  Please run this command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this post,

[Assets not found by Cordova/Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410066/assets-not-found-by-cordova-phonegap)

---

I found the answer was that someone had introduced

```
<base href="/">
```

and I needed

```
<base href=".">
```

could be helpful...

Comment: I am building...still fails. The paths in the script tags are relative. I updated the question with screenshots, including the script tags.

Comment: ok maybe you should look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410066/assets-not-found-by-cordova-phonegap

Comment: Wow, that worked! If you modify your answer I'll accept it. Then hopefully others who stumble across this question can benefit. Thanks!

Comment: Done, thanks, it would be awesome to have it as a accepted answer... cheers and happy coding :)