# angularjs cordova base href

Tags: angularjs, html, cordova, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

trying to set the correct `base href` value for an angularjs html5 web app to work in cordova

initially using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` with  `<base href="/">`:

- app works perfectly in a normal browser
- cordova gives resource errors for css / js / templates etc
  (I believe it looks for resources within the cordova root directory rather than the platform root?)

Tried a few alternatives are floated around here on SO and ui-router [FAQs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#issue-my-assets-and-templates-are-not-loading):

`<base href=".">` with html5 mode as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26467406/3092596) answer  :

- assets are found ok in cordova (no resource errors)
- ui-router goes into a tail-spin with infinite loop and the following error message
  `Error: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https://page/' cannot be created in a document with origin https://example.com`

`<base href="./">` with html5 mode:

- assets found in cordova (no resource errors)
- gives me the dreaded `Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!` message
  tried using [frankwallis solution](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/600#issuecomment-47228922) mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25755152/3092596) but that didn't help (same error)

no `base href` with `$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});`

- assets found in cordova (no resource errors)
- pages start loading inside themselves ?? ...like angular bootstraps twice in *some* states ?

my app config definition looks like:

```
myApp.config(['$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$stickyStateProvider', function($locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $stickyStateProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider
    .state('root', {            // we define a 'root' state so that we can load some essential data prior to any template being loaded
        url: '',
        abstract: true,
        sticky: true,
        views: {
            'root': {
                template: '<ui-view/>',
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.worldmap', {
        url : '/worldmap',
        templateUrl : 'templates/worldmap.tmpl.html'
    })
    .state('root.faq', {
        url : '/faq',
        templateUrl : 'templates/faq.tmpl.html'
    })
    .state("otherwise", {
        url: "*path",
        views: {
            'root': {
                template: "",
                controller: ['$injector', function($injector) {
                    var $state = $injector.get("$state");
                    $state.go('root.worldmap');
                }]
            }
        },
    });
    $stickyStateProvider.enableDebug(true);
}]);
```

For info: 
using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27450072/3092596) of alternative cordova `deviceready` vs angular.element bootstrap for cordova / browser respectively

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK so the way to get this working is by removing the base href ***AND*** disabling html5 mode :

- [optional] create & checkout a new branch called `dev-cordova` or similar

  - this allows you to switch quickly between browser and device code
- delete / comment the `<base href="/">` in the main `index.html`
- ensure that html5 mode is *disabled* in `app.js` by either

  ```
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: false,
      requireBase: false
  });
  ```

  or

  ```
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
  ```

Don't forget to run `cordova build ios` (after you grunt / gulp etc to compile the js files)
...this ensures the files in the cordova `/platforms/ios/www` directory are updated.

Comment: Images are not loading for me.
I am using path ./images/logo.png and images/logo.png.
Any idea?